# CDI: Interface from jar cannot be resolved as Local Wildfly 8.0

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly

I am trying to migrate existing Java 7 application from Jboss 7.1 to Wildfly 8.0 and facing some problems with CDI.

The structure of a project is following:

```
 ear
    |
    |--> base.service.impl.war
    |--> mad.impl.war --> contains SessionServiceImpl.class
    |--> lib
        |
        |-> base.api.jar
        |-> base.api.impl.jar --> contains SessionService.class
```

SessionService is plain Java interface with no annotations.
SessionServiceImpl looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = SessionService.JNDI_NAME, beanInterface = SessionService.class)
public class SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService {

}
```

The EJB seems to be registered:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named SessionServiceImpl in deployment unit subdeployment "com.mad.impl.war" of deployment "com.deployment.ear.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/com.server.deployment.ear/com.mad.impl/SessionServiceImpl!com.base.session.SessionService
    java:app/com.mad.impl/SessionServiceImpl!com.base.session.SessionService
    java:module/SessionServiceImpl!com.base.session.SessionService
    java:global/com.deployment.ear/com.mad.impl/SessionServiceImpl
    java:app/com.mad.impl/SessionServiceImpl
    java:module/SessionServiceImpl
```

But after that when CDI container starts deployment I am getting following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."com.deployment.ear.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."com.deployment.ear.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.deployment.subunit."com.deployment.ear.ear"."com.mad.impl.war".component.SessionServiceImpl.VIEW."com.base.session.SessionService".LOCAL not found
```

I've tried to annotate interface with @Local, but that didn't helped.

Maven ear-plugin configuration is following:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <initializeInOrder>true</initializeInOrder>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.base.impl</artifactId>
                        </jarModule>

                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.base.service.impl</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/impl.base.server</contextRoot>
                            <bundleFileName>com.base.impl.war</bundleFileName>
                        </webModule>

                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.mad.impl</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/impl.mad.server</contextRoot>
                            <bundleFileName>com.mad.impl.war</bundleFileName>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Any reason why don't you use latest 8.2.1 or even 9.0.1 release? There is a good chance that problem you have was already fixed.

Comment: Good point. Initial reason was that I couldn't find appropriate server adapter for Eclipse Kepler and I didn't wanted to spend much time looking for it (since it is low priority task atm.). But you are right, I shall try to migrate to 9.0.1

Comment: you can always find latest WildFly/Jboss adapters for eclipse under jboss tools project http://tools.jboss.org/

Comment: Yes, but at the moment I can see, that only Wildfly 8.0 is supported.

Comment: 8.2 and 9 should work as well http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-04-02-devstudio-8.1.0.GA-for-luna.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried to manually deploy to 8.2.1 and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Stateless bean. CDI has problems with injecting Remote interfaces for session beans. As the error shows you, it is trying to inject the LOCAL interface for SessionServiceImpl, but that cannot happen, since the ejb container (based on ejb spec) has only exposed a remote interface since your SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService, and is not annotated with @LocalBean.

Note about ejb3.1:

- If a session bean implements any interface other than Serializable,
  Comparable, Externalizable, then the implemented interface will be
  considered as a remote interface for the bean.
- Additionally, you have defined, using the @EJB annotation, the remote
  interface for your SessionServiceImpl, and hence it is not placed in
  LOCAL namespace, but in REMOTE namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I now managed to deploy these parts, which were previously failing. Don't really know why it started to work now:)

Answer (score 0):

In the end removing `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>` from application.xml seemed to do a trick. (https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243482). Also, I had to replace some `@Inject` annotations with `@EJB`.